# Does Sub Power Up affect clams?

Tags: splatoon-2

In Clam Blitz you can throw clams with the L button and it shows a line that looks similar to the line when you throw a bomb, so does Sub Power Up affect throwing clams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Clams are not your sub, so they don't get affected by that. The different abilities you can get don't affect anything except your character and your weapons.